# Database in Rails App updates before a Prawn PDF report can be drawn up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

My rails app changes the state of an item, but when it does so, there are potential errors that a user can encounter. I am developing a way to allow the user to override those errors, and afterwards create a pdf report so that they can print it out as a receipt of what they have done.

Here is the code that develops the report and completes the action on each item:

```
def report
  ids = params[:ids].split()
  @items = Item.order("id").where(id: ids)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf { prawnto(page_size: "A4", inline: true)}
  end

  @items.each do |item|
    item.action
  end
end
```

My problem is that, in order to test for errors (for instance, incompatible states of the item), I need to test the item *before* the action put into effect.

Every test I have done so far indicates that the items.each do block is being evaluated before the report is complete. My app requires the inverse.

Any help and/or an explanation as to why this behaviour is occurring would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller code runs to completion before doing any rendering. Moving the order around does nothing here because that block you've given for `pdf` format is ignored until the very end. There's no obligation for it to be executed immediately because of where you've defined it.

If you really need it done first, capture the result of your report, then use that in the rendering method:

```
# Execute the report immediately.
report_pdf = prawnto(...)

respond_to do |format|
  format.pdf { report_pdf }
end
```